How to loop cut multiple faces?
How can I loop cut all the selected faces in half? Or multiple times? In 3ds max this is called connect edge.


The answer is Edge > Subdivide

Although it's done what you asked, a true loop cut would add an edge round the entire object, not just subdividing the selected edges.

@JohnEason A "true" loop cut might add an edge around the entire object, but the question explicitly asks to cut the selected faces, not the complete object. The Loop Cut and Slide tool doesn't always cut around the entire object either - if it reaches an edge that's part of an n-gon it stops the loop cut there.

You can also make a loop cut Ctrl + R (or Cmd + R Mac) and point where you want to cut.
With the mouse wheel you can select the number of cuts.
With this option you have to select 1 by 1 the areas you want to cut if you don't want to cut all your geometry.
Subdivide works too but it splits your selection in every direction.
